# Как реализовать тайм-аут на кнопке?

Tags: java, android, таймер, countdowntimer

Я хочу поставить на кнопку что-то вроде таймера, то есть у меня есть кнопка, после нажатия она становится неактивной, скажем, на 2 часа, через два часа она снова активируется, но таймер продолжает отсчитывать время, даже если Приложение закрыто или свернуто. Как сделать кнопку неактивной, я знаю, поможет понять, как сделать таймер.

Я написал код так, чтобы, когда я нажимал кнопку, она записывала дату и деактивировала кнопку, а после этого она получала новую дату и находила разницу, а когда она составляла 10 секунд, она снова активировала кнопку, но код не работает, объясните почему?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    private String TAG;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);




        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setEnabled(false);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                editor.putLong("Time", startTime);
                editor.apply();
                Log.d(TAG, "Time " + startTime);
            }
        });

        long startMillis = preferences.getLong("Time", 0);
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d(TAG, "Now " + now);
        long difference = now - startMillis;

        if (difference == 10000) {
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Time111: " + difference);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит: код не работает?

Comment: Кнопка деактивируется и все, больше ничего не происходит и то после перезапуска приложения снова активна

Comment: Ну судя по коду так и должно быть. Он проверяет разницу только на старте. Если вы хотите ongoing проверку - вынесите ее в отдельный поток, который будтет сигнализировать о наступлении события. Если вы хотите, чтобы она становился доступной в текущей активности, используйте отсроченное через `Handler()` выполнение кода `setEnabled(true)`. Если вам нужно делать проверку только на старте - оставьте как естт

Comment: не, надо чтобы при любой активности приложения он проверял

Comment: Одна активность не имеет (не должна иметь) доступа к view другой. Как вариант - поставить проверку в `onResume()`, чтобы она срабатывала на возврате в нужную активность

Comment: Не, активность я имел ввиду не Activity)

Comment: Ну, наверное, тогда лучше отдельный поток с уведомлением + в onResume(). Но тут много нюансов: если активити не видно (и view нет), если активности нет (и потока нет) - нужно отдельно обрабатывать